# Testing a `PrincipalContext` using `ValidateCredentials(null, null)` behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core, principalcontext

I need to validate the credentials that are used to connect to an AD server. If if pass invalid credentials to `PrincipalContext(ContextType, String, String, String)`, `PrincipalContext.ConnectedServer` throws a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException` which is discovered on the first use of the `PrincipalContext`.

I am trying to test the credentials with `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(null, null)` but I am having issues. According to the [.NET Core 2.0 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials?view=netcore-2.0)

> The ValidateCredentials method binds to the server specified in the constructor. If the username and password parameters are null, the credentials specified in the constructor are validated.

I create a connnection to the server.

```
string username = "username"
string password = "password"

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my_domain.local", username, password);
```

And then to test the connection I try:

```
if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(null, null))
{
    // This block does not get hit!
    // This is surprising because the credentials are valid
}
```

Which has different behaviour to:

```
if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
{
    // Credentials are valid, this block gets hit
}
```

The docs lead me to believe these calls should behave identically yet I am experiencing different results. Why is this and what is the proper way to test a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this by running your code under a local account on my computer and passing valid domain credentials in the constructor. `ValidateCredentials(null, null)` does indeed fail.

This sounds like a bug, either in the code or in the documentation, so I've filed a bug on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29369

*Edit:* looks like they've decided to leave the implementation as-is and correct the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gabriel. Do you know the proper way to test a connection or should I write a follow up question?

Comment: Reading the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs), it looks like just creating a new `PrincipalContext` object tests the connection.

Comment: The the details are too big for a comment so I have posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097199/how-to-validate-the-credentials-passed-to-a-principalcontext). This wasn't quite the answer I wanted but it has helped I'm accepting it.